# Load from HIVE table into HDFS as AVRO file

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql, avro

I want to load a file into HDFS (as **.avro** file) from HIVE table.
Currently I am able to move a table as a file from HIVE to HDFS but I am not able to specify a particular format of my Target file. can some one help me in this.??

Answer (score 0):

So your question is really

> How do I convert a Hive table to a different storage format?

Create a new table with the same fields and types as the avro table and change the input format.  Then insert into the new table from the old table.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.
My question is how do i load a file into HDFS from HIVE table.
The target file in HDFS shouls be an avro file.

As per your input, I am just convertig the input format of an HIVE table.

Comment: @Jomy : If you create the table with avro storage, the data **is** storing in HDFS, usually at "/user/hive/warehouse/<db_name>/<table>" you can just copy the data file out.